# Unable to locate a button Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, automated-refactoring

I need to click on CC to verify if its working.Can't figure out, It gives me error.

```
public void cc() {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class*='vjs-subs-caps-button']"));
}
```

Here is the HTML CODE:

```
<button class="vjs-control vjs-button vjs-subs-caps-button"
   type="button" aria-live="polite" aria-disabled="false" title="Closed
   Captions" aria-pressed="false"><span aria-hidden="true"
   class="vjs-icon-placeholder"></span><span
   class="vjs-control-text">Closed Captions</span> </button></div>
```

Comment: Try with this driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.vjs-subs-caps-button"))

Comment: Please update question with Error stack trace. Thanks